# Android export give a "Conversion to Dalvik format failed error1"

Tags: android, eclipse

When i try to export my android project i'm getting the following eclipse error message  "Conversion to Dalvik format failed error1""

i try the following steps but no luck..

- Project » Clean
- add `-Xms128m /-Xmx512m` to `eclipse.ini`
- Restarting Eclipse with the -clean option

Export Steps:
 - Right click on project->export->android under that select the "export android application"

Comment: Hey naruto fan, you should accept the answer of vggonz.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Disable "Build Automatically" on "Project Menu" and rebuild it manually (Right click on project -> Build project), then try to export the application again.

Eclipse seems to conflict with export and compile simultaneously. So every time you need to export an APK, disable automatic build. It's safe to use it any other time.