# When exporting a signed Android project, I'm getting Dalvik error 1

Tags: android

I've read some similar questions about this problem, but unlike the solutions proposed in those, I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with Proguard or duplicate jars.

This error only occurs when trying to export as a signed APK. Just compiling and running on a device doesn't cause any problem.

I've tried the following:

- Cleaning the project
- Restarting Eclipse
- Deleting my bin folder
- Removing and restoring all libraries
- Creating a new project from scratch

The problem doesn't go away. Just a few days ago I was able to export without issue. I don't have a Proguard file, and the proguard line is commented out in the project.properties file. I've also checked thoroughly, and the jar files are not duplicates, nor do they contain duplicate classes within (I haven't added any new libs since my successful exports last week).

Are there any other known ways to solve this problem? I'm ready to punch Eric Schmidt in the mouth.

Comment: Check you libraries, make sure there are no possible classes with same class path.

Comment: Yea I did that and there aren't. I'm extra sure too cause my libraries haven't changed for weeks and just a few days ago exporting worked fine. Also, I'm pretty sure conflicting libraries will prevent you from even compiling, not just exporting.

Comment: Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161852/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-export-only

Comment: Tried that, didn't solve anything.