# Export APK from Eclipse produces error "No Build Tools installed in the SDK"

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

My ability to export APKs from Eclipse (Juno for Mac) broke today after doing an update.  I can get to the Finish button (after specifying keystore and release passwords), and, when I click that I get a popup that reads "No Build Tools installed in the SDK"

Here's what I have installed now (the Android stuff had previously been 21.*):

Android DDMS  22.0.0.v201305140200--675183    com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group  The Android Open Source Project

Android Development Tools 22.0.0.v201305140200--675183    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group   The Android Open Source Project

Android Hierarchy Viewer  22.0.0.v201305140200--675183    com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group   The Android Open Source Project
  Android Traceview 22.0.0.v201305140200--675183    com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group The Android Open Source Project

CollabNet Merge Client  3.0.13  com.collabnet.subversion.merge.feature.feature.group    CollabNet

Eclipse IDE for Mobile Developers 1.5.2.20130211-1820 epp.package.mobile  null

JNA Library   3.4.0.t20120117_1605    net.java.dev.jna.feature.group  null

Subclipse (Required)  1.8.20  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.feature.group   tigris.org

Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional)    3.0.0   org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.mylyn.feature.group tigris.org

Subversion Client Adapter (Required)  1.8.4   org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.feature.feature.group   tigris.org

Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter  1.7.9.1 org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.feature.feature.group    tigris.org

Subversion Revision Graph 1.1.1   org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.graph.feature.feature.group tigris.org

SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required)  1.7.9.1 org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.svnkit.feature.feature.group    tigris.org

SVNKit Library    1.7.8.r9538_v20130107_2001  org.tmatesoft.svnkit.feature.group  TMate Software

Tracer for OpenGL ES  22.0.0.v201305140200--675183    com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.group    The Android Open Source Project

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Lauch the sdk manager and download the new package  **Android SDK Build-tools** which didn't get installed automaticaly when you update to ADT 22

Comment: This is the fix.  One word of caution: after I applied this and restarted, I got this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161852/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-export-only.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I downloaded the 64bit version of eclipse and then mistakenly downloaded the 32 bit version of adt.   I deleted the adt and downloaded the 64 bit version and it worked.