# Emulator not showing the updated output after making the changes in the code

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

Yesterday i updated eclipse and sdk, and now have made some changes to the code but not able to see the changes made in emulator when i run it.
These are the things i have tried by googling:

1. restarted eclipse and avd
2. clean the project
3. checked whether all the options are checked under project
   properties->builders.
4. Checked whether all the options are checked under
   windows->preferences->android->build

When I tried to test it on device, I was not able to export, but got "No Build Tools installed in the sdk".
So I installed the tools in the sdk, but I still could not get updated output.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: First uninstall the previous apk and then install it again.

Comment: i installed and tested in new emulator@Kumar but still no use

Comment: Do you get any error when you build your project? Does it create a new APK after any build?

Comment: not able to create apk, while exporting the project i'm getting that "No build tools installed in the sdk" message. @SamRad

Comment: Open SDK manager and select `Android SDK build tools` under `Tools`. Then install.

Comment: Under Tools, i'm getting "Android sdk Tools, Android sdk platform toosl, Android sdk build tools" these 3 are already installed @SamRad

Comment: @jack, Open the SDK folder see if the `build-tools` directory is empty or not?

Comment: Never mind. Check this: [Android Sdk tools Revision 22 issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16583786/1693859)

Comment: thanks for replies, i had done according to your suggested link, again dint workout, not only for the current for all the project in eclipse its not getting updated, @SamRad

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the latest apk is getting installed on the device? There are some instances where it will not overwrite an installed apk. For example if your build-signing key has changed recently. Try uninstalling the app fully from the device first, and try again.

Comment: i'm not able to export the project from eclipse, when i do that i'm getting, "No build tools installed in the sdk" message. @Ken Wolf

Comment: Does this help? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596886/export-apk-from-eclipse-produces-error-no-build-tools-installed-in-the-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Go to device manager edit device virtually created by you or system ..you will find one check box saying enable snaps shot. check mark it. it will work..

Comment: Did this also, but dont know where i'm going wrong @user2120794