# How do I disable proGuard?

Tags: eclipse, proguard

I am getting upwards of 5k errors when I try to sign my app because of proguard. How do I disable proguard? I have tried every example  on stackoverflow and even some form other sources, not how I wanted to spend Christmas Eve.

I tried remove the proguard from the project.properties, which obviously causes a davlik error. I can't find any way to remove or disable it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning Proguard On/Off Using Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642030/turning-proguard-on-off-using-properties)

Comment: No it isn't. I don't have any build.properties file, and debug is set on and off dynamically by eclipse, it's not something I should be setting any more. Exporting signed application will always do so with release version.

Comment: can you  show the screen shot of error or log file ? is it _Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1_ ?? You are using latest ADT rigt?

Answer (score 2):

ProGuard is disabled by default. You can enable it for Eclipse and Ant by removing the hash character of the line with `proguard.config` in `project.properties`. You can disable it again by commenting out the line again:

```
#proguard.config=.....
```

You can enable ProGuard in Gradle by adding the setting `runProguard=true` in `build.gradle`. You can disable it again by removing that setting.

With ProGuard disabled, whatever errors you see must have different origins.

Comment: This might lead you to an error described here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564816/android-export-give-a-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-error1

The accepted answer fixed my problem